# Image style in D7

Tags: theming

The following code I used once in node.tpl.php template to construct a jquery gallery in Drupal 6 where I found somewhere.

```
 <ul id="jgallery">    

   <?php foreach($field_myimage as $key => $image):?>                  
    <li><?php print theme('imagecache', 'imagecache_name', $image['filepath']); ?></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>                                                   

 </ul>
```

I wonder how it should be used in Drupal 7, the image style. And how to add in extra attributes like class. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think [theme_image_style()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) is what you're looking for.

Eg:

```
$image = array(
    'style_name' => 'style_name', // imagecache_name
    'path' => $image_uri, //  uri (String, 27 characters ) public://image.jpg
    'alt' => 'Alt text here',
    'title' => 'Title text here',
);

print theme('image_style', $image);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can anyone convert for me into D7. I'm still a newbie to this programming. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer